# Relative paths of CSS and images in htaccess, creating nice URLs

Tags: css, image, .htaccess, path, relative-path

Trying to do nice URLs. When I have a URL like this: `http://nove.illusions-media.cz/nase-sluzby` everythink is OK. But when the URL is `http://nove.illusions-media.cz/nase-sluzby/tvorba-webu` CSS and images do not work.

This is how my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?stranka=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ ?stranka=$1&podstranka=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Add a <base href="/"> in head part of your document.